# How do I treat the results of Fit as text?

Tags: fitting, text

I would like to take the results of `Fit` (or any `FittedModel`) and treat them as text, including making substitutions for the variables. But I can't figure out how to do this.

For example

```
"Subscript[I, m]/Subscript[I, r]" <> " = " <> ToString[Fit[currentRatio[32],{1,x,x^2,x^3},x]/.x->"Subscript[I, r]"]
```

produces the garbled output

```
Subscript[I, m]/Subscript[I, r] =                                      -6   2             -10   3
0.591585 + 0.00126235 I  - 1.75804 10   I   + 8.08979 10    I
                       r                 r                   r
```

How do I treat the results of `Fit` or `FittedModel` as text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"Subscript[I, m]/Subscript[I, r]" <> " = " <> 
   ToString[Fit[Table[{x, x + x^3}, {x, 0, 1, .1}], {1, x, x^2, x^3},  x] /. 
      x -> "Subscript[I, r]", StandardForm]
```

[image]

With `InputForm` inplace of `StandardForm` we get

> "Subscript[I, m]/Subscript[I, r] = 0. + 
>   0.9999999999999991*\"Subscript[I, r]\" + 
>   2.511131286529154*^-15*\"Subscript[I, r]\"^2 + 
>   0.9999999999999988*\"Subscript[I, r]\"^3"

**Note:** [ToString >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToString.html):

> `ToString` *supports the same set of options as* `OpenAppend`, *with default settings* `FormatType->OutputForm`, `PageWidth->Infinity`, `TotalWidth->Infinity`.

```
 ToString[x^2]
```

[image]

```
 ToString[x^2, StandardForm]
```

[image]

```
 ToString[x^2, InputForm]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just use Row:

```
Row[
  {Subscript[I, m]/Subscript[I, r] , 
   " = ", 
   Fit[Table[{x, x + x^3}, {x, 0, 1, .1}], {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x] /. 
     x -> Subscript[I, r]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: If I try to join that with a string as in the OP I get the same error: "StringJoin::string: String expected at position 2 in...".

Comment: With  Row[...] you can combine strings and Style-objects!

Comment: It never fails that no matter what I'm trying to do, I eventually reach the point where I kick myself and ask: Why didn't I just do this in Python!